# Why this decimals in pixels when loading a page in Chrome locally?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I’m experiencing strange html page renderizations in **Chrome** when executed **locally** (with Tomcat).
Analysing the code with the html code inspector I see a lot of **decimals** everywhere in the pixel sizes here and there.

Look at these two **screenshots**, with corresponds to the following **snippets**:

BAD-LOCAL-SAMPLE:

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<img 
    style="-webkit-user-select: none" 
    src="http://localhost:8080/showcase-labs/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo">
</body>
</html>
```

GOOD-REMOTE-SAMPLE:

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<img 
    style="-webkit-user-select: none" 
    src="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo">
</body>
</html>
```

[image: bad]

[image: good]

This is a simplification case of a more complex one.
Could somebody provide me some hints?
Could somebody provide a JQuery function to round those decimals for the whole DOM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing similar non-integer dimensions in the inspector when my browser window is zoomed. Click on "Actual size" in the "View" menu to reset the zoom level to 100%.

Comment: You are right. My Chrome was running with 110% zoom. Problem solved!!

Comment: urghhh - I can't believe I just wasted 3 hours trying to figure this out.